# Testing across activities using Robotium

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, robotium, accounts

I have to write a test which basically open's the Android->Accounts and sync -> Add Accounts -> *(then fill the login information)*
and go back to Accounts and sync and check if the account has been added.

Currently the best I have been able to do was create a Test which opens Android Add Accounts
then I have to manually add the account
then I have an automated test to Open Accounts and Sync page
then another test which checks if I am able to send REST-http calls to my server, which shows an account has been added.

I want to know if there is anyway to get this to work in a flow and automate the whole process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AndroidViewClient](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/) which uses monkeyrunner. By doing this, you will be having control over entire device, not just your application.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. This may sound silly but does AndroidViewClient give me access only over the UI or the functionality too?

Comment: Only UI (basically it is a wrapper over monkeyrunner). But still you can access adb logcat or adb shell commands

Comment: I tried AndroidViewClient it is a good tool but it still doesn't exactly do what I needed. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

What you might want is to use the new android testing framework from android.

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

Comment: that looks promising, I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried uiautomatorviewer, its helpful but not exactly still solving my issue. Thanks for the tip though, its a useful tool....

Comment: What is it that you cannot do with it?

Comment: I wanted to test the the Login activity age, that you get after you click an account you want to add from android accounts and sync

Comment: The only way you will be able to do that is to use the ViewClient (on an emulator or development device (that is different to a device with developer mode on)) or to use the UI Testing (which will only work with Jellybean+). They can both do what you want, so i am unsure in what way they do not solve your issue. What problems are you having using them that you need help with? Is this in the middle of a test case? You cannot do what you want with robotium.

Comment: Ok m activity starts off from android's email loginactivity (you get there usually by Settings -> accounts -> Add account -> *select your accont* )
and from there I navigate back to an activity in my package.
main issues for me were that I cannot navigate from an activity in my package to an activity of another package
and, Android is not programmatically letting my launch the email-login page as my launcher activity.
I hope i made sense.